# Property 'firebase' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' how to propperly annotate?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm providing my firebase object through a higher order component like this:

```
const FirebaseContextInterfaceLocal: FirebaseContextInterface = {
  value: new Firebase()
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={FirebaseContextInterfaceLocal}>
      <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And after that I'm using it like this:

```
const ForgotPassword: React.FC = ({ firebase }) => {

}

export default withFirebase(ForgotPassword)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'firebase' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

I'm trying to find out how to properly annotate this but I can't find any good explanation. Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `value` key instead of firebase

```
const ForgotPassword: React.FC = ({ value }) => {

}

export default withFirebase(ForgotPassword)
```

or try to change the property of `FirebaseContextInterfaceLocal` to:

```
const FirebaseContextInterfaceLocal = {
  firebase: new Firebase()
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <FirebaseContext.Provider firebase={FirebaseContextInterfaceLocal.firebase}>
      <App />
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

So you can do this:

```
const ForgotPassword: React.FC = ({ firebase }) => {

}

export default withFirebase(ForgotPassword)
```